# How to bat function redirects to a file?

Tags: windows, batch-file

Everyone

How do bat functions redirect to a file?

Example:

```
:func
call run-server.bat %* 2>&1 >>./server.log
goto:eof
call :func %* 2>&1 >>./run.log
```

Answer (score 1):

In Windows (just like in UNIX/Linux) you can redirect to an output file using the `>` character:

```
>  : write to file (recreate a new file if needed)
>> : append to file (create the file if it does not exist yet)
```

Examples:

```
echo tralala >writetofile.txt
echo tralala >writetofile.txt

echo tralala >>appendtofile.txt
echo tralala >>appendtofile.txt
```

file "writetofile.txt":

```
tralala
```

file "appendtofile.txt":

```
tralala
tralala
```

The expression `2>&1`, which is used for redirecting error output to the standard output in Linux and UNIX environments, is not used in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
set "var=a string with a caret^ and an > arrow"

call :SomeFunc var
exit /b

:SomeFunc
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "param1=!%1!"
echo !param1!
exit /b
```

Comment: thank you , but that like linux "nohup" ?